# Show the ”welcome” message only for the new users in the Telegram group

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

I am an admin of some Telegram group. I added a bot to it. For every new user, I deleting the old welcome message and adding the new one, to reduce the number of irrelevant messages.

Is there any way to show the ”welcome” message only to a specific user? Or to send him a private message with a ”welcome” message? Or maybe any other interesting solution that you have to show information for specific users only without spamming others?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to show the ”welcome” message only to a specific
> user?

The answer is NO! You can't send users private message if they haven't started the bot, and if you do that, you get an error:

*Bad Request: chat not found*

---

- You may send welcome messages and delete them after a while.
- You may save new users somewhere and check your list every minute; if
  it isn't empty, send a single welcome message and mention all of
  them, and clear your list for the next minute.